# Ubuntu 13.10 and ROS from source

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I am trying to install ROS Hydro from source on my fresh install of 13.10.  The reason being is I have be a shiny new laptop with a Haswell chip that REALLY doesn't play nice with previous versions of gcc before 4.8.

Anyways, I was going through the source install tutorial

http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source

and it mentions that you need to grab the source list for this distribution:

> If you have trouble installing the packages in the command above, make sure you have added the packages.ros.org debian repository to your apt source lists as described starting here: hydro/Installation/Ubuntu#hydro.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list

The problem is that there is no source list for saucy on the page mentioned.  I know that there are no debian packages for saucy, but where are the source lists so I can install things like python-rosdep etc.  Do I need to compile those from source too?

I know that people have managed to get this working, just not sure how.
Thanks for the help!

Cheers,
Kel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/116976/ubuntu-13.10-and-ros-from-source/) by [Kel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1972/kel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2014-01-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the raring line as a template and substitute `raring` with `saucy`. The repository will not contain any ROS packages but all Python tools necessary to build ROS from source (like `python-rosdep`).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1972/kel/) on 2014-01-10**:
Thanks!  And I just ignore the warning about the packages not being authenticated?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-01-10**:
Yes, that is the case for all ROS repos currently.